# Is there any evidence black holes can grow (gain mass) by accretion?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, event-horizon, singularities

When LIGO detected GW150914, we saw for the first time the merger of 2 black holes and the gravitational wave evidence fit with our models and understanding for such an event. (Horizon meeting horizon).

However, is there any direct evidence that black holes grow (gain mass) by accretion/in-falling matter? (Matter meeting horizon). (GW200105 and GW200115 neutron star black hole mergers?). In the timescales of measured observables, can we actually ‘see’ a black hole get bigger?

Does the infalling mass remain with the system add to the mass (and thus gravitational field of) the black hole? Does the event horizon get bigger? How do we know the mass isn’t ‘deleted’?

(Edit: trying to simplify as much as I can. )

Comment: While you're waiting for this to be re-opened, you might want to read up on [GW200105 & GW200115.](https://www.ligo.org/detections/NSBH2020.php)

Comment: Thanks and good link.

Answer (score 0):

Mass accumulation rates typically are limited by the Eddington luminosity (where the light pressure starts blowing away the accreting material) giving a rate $\approx 1.5\cdot10^{17}(M/M_\odot)$ g/s which is far smaller than the mass $M$ ([this remains true for super-Eddington accretion too](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Accretion_discs)). So we should not expect to see any noticeable growth of a black hole during observation.

Indirectly, one can infer that mass is moving inward since it releases potential energy in the form of a hot accretion disk.

[Observations and model fits](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0312033) typically produce an inner disc edge a few multiples of the Schwarzschild radius. Did matter not enter the black hole it would have to somehow pile up there without radiating, which is implausible given that a typical accretion disk is full of very hot hydrogen that would tend to visibly fuse rather energetically if compressed together (let alone the lack of plausible way of stopping the infall).

Comment: Thanks. The question is what happens to the mass at or after the horizon. Since this pathway can never be measured, how do we know the mass isn’t ‘deleted’ by being accelerated to light speed. For example with the black hole neutron star merger, what does the resultant combined object look like after the merger? Is the new black hole bigger after swallowing the star? Or is the neutron star ‘deleted’?

Comment: Note that merger events give information about the resulting object mass through the ringdown waves, allowing estimation of it (and losses due to waves). In mergers the new black hole is bigger, as expected.